# В Xcode в файле h не создаются проперти CG (CGFloat, CGRect)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Нашёл выход путём импорта CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h. Если не импортировать библиотеку, то вот что пишет[image: если раскомментировать импорт CoreGraphics, то всё становится нормально]
Извиняюсь если вопрос глупый, но при просмотре обучающего видео автор создаёт проперти без дополнительного импорта чего-либо. Хотелось бы исправить этот момент.
такие же симптомы при вызове метода NSStringFromCGPoint(p)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] если добавляю UIKit/UIKit.h, то всё становится нормально.
Благодарю заранее!

Comment: А в чем вопрос? Добавьте нужные библиотеки UIKit и CoreGraphics. Скорее всего у автора обучающего видео эти библиотеки прописаны в файле ...Prefix.pch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, автор видео использует [Precompiled Header File](http://arm1.ru/blog/poleznaya-shtuka-prefix-pch) (.PCH), в котором подключает необходимые библиотеки (UIKit, CoreGraphics и др.) всего один раз.